# Best approach for binding native query results in JAVA when the total number of parameters differs

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a spring rest api and i am using jpa to create a native query to fetch some data. But the query is not always the same. The number of parameters to be binded differ based on conditions. Here is the code that i am using:

```
public List<CustomObject> getMyData(String param1, String param2, String param3, int param4, .......) {
   StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
   sql.append("SELECT //some columns")
      .append(" FROM //some tables")
      .append(" WHERE //joins and default conditions");

   int counter = 0;
   Map<Integer, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap();

   if (!param1.isEmpty()) {
      query.append("AND column1 = ?");
      counter++;
      params.put(counter, param1);
   }

   if (!param2.isEmpty()) {
      query.append("AND column2 = ?");
      counter++;
      params.put(counter, param2);
   }

   // .... the same all remaining params

   try {
       Query q = emORA.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
       params.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
           q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
       });

       //execute query and fetch results
   } catch () {
      //handle exeptions
   }
}
```

My question is:
Because the total number of parameters varies, i use a LinkedHashMap to store the position and the actual value to be binded. Is there a better approach than using LinkedHashMap for this situation?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a frail solution (but you know your constraints). For eg right now this sql will be invalid because when you append the param strings you forgot to put a leading white space. And maybe you'll need to have different comparators in the future, not only `=`. Criteria API seems like a better tool for the job

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The leading space is my bad, i did it wrong only in the question. I'll try your proposal and see. Thank you again.